# Document Library adding spans and divs

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, branding

I want to customize my document library edit and new form according to my client's need but I am unable to do so in SharePoint 2013 online.

Is it even possible to do so OOTB? I am just a beginner.

Please help me with this if possible.

My task is to validate all the fields and if found wrong entries, give alerts on the form itself.

Also provide divs/spans under fields, for example for 'NAME' field it should have one descriptive filed below it such as `Name should be in capital letters only`.

Comment: Which type of customization you need to do? Please provide that details in your question.

Comment: Edition done Dikesh, please have a llok over it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Column Description

You can add field description from editing the field. That description will be shown below input control.

Add you description from edit column
 Go to **Library settings** >> **Columns** >> **Choose column to edit**

[image]

Your description will be shown as below image in default add/edit form:

[image]

### Form Validation

- You can add **JavaScript/jQuery code** to validate fields in form. (You can set alerts using code as per your requirement)

**UPDATE**

Add content editor webpart on `http://<servername>/<libraryname>/Forms/EditForm.aspx` page. And attach javascript functions to this form.
Using **PreSaveAction** Check [here](https://workflowssimplified.wordpress.com/2011/06/09/sharepoint-2010-validation-using-javascript/).

- You can add **formula** to validate particular column in OOTB way. It will show error message below each input control in red font color.
- [Very effective way]: You can create **Customized Visual Web part** for that in sandbox solution for O365/SharePoint Online. In which you can validate your form (Give alerts) as per your requirement and also add column description as you per your desire as HTML form is completely under your control.

Comment: Thank you Dikesh for your answer, it will solve my current needs. But when i try to add alerts using jquery for document library it doesn't works(within the server side default form), though it works fine for lists. Also for your second option, most of my columns are lookups and it doesn't works for lookups.      PS :- I am completely unaware about the third solution as i am just a beginner in SharePoint.  Please enlighten me with these customized visual web part in sandbox solution( is it on-prem?) and share any references for tutorials for these.

Comment: Also i am unable to edit the 'Name' column in document library as it is a system column. If i could remove it and make a new column such as 'File Name', but that's too not possible for me right now.

Comment: Then go for custom solution as it will give more power for customization. You can edit other then system columns in library.

Comment: That is my question Dikesh, what custom solution you talking about? Where should i learn it from? What will i need for it?

Comment: Using visual studio create one sandbox solution, in which create one visual webpart , in that create html form and write logic for validation and document upload logic on button click event using C#/javascript.

Comment: Updated my answer for javascript validation

Comment: Thank you so much Dikesh! That certainly has helped me with my work.

Comment: Very happy to help you 